# (Laravel) Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Intentando hacer composer update obtengo siempre el siguente error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                                                            
 copy(/home/user/.composer/cache/files/nexmo/client/9a77c8d9a60db16a277ace89703c6d841e17b77a.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltan los permisos

```
chgrp -R www storage bootstrap/cache public
chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache public
chown www:www -R ./
```

cambia www:www por tu usuario y grupo